# i don't get any value from document.getElementById(id).value

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the value from a simple html textfield but whenever i write something and press enter no value is saved. i tried comparing the input from the textfield with a simple == but nothing works. I don't even get any value for console.log(textervalue). Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

```
<div class="splitscreen" >
    <div class="left">
        <video class="input_video"></video>
        <canvas class="output_canvas" width="960" height="540" id="rand"></canvas>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
        <canvas class="chat_canvas" width="250" height="500" id="rundrand" ></canvas>
        
        <form action="/url" method="GET" id="rand_text">
        <input type="text" id ='texter' value='Guess here' autocomplete ='off'>
        </form>
        
    </div>
</div>
```

```
var read = 'car';
```

```
textervalue = document.getElementById("texter").value;

//just to test if i get a value
if (textervalue == read)
{
  canchat.fillStyle="#FFFFF";
  canchat.fillRect(0,0, canvasChat.width, canvasChat.height);
}

console.log(textervalue);
```

Comment: How are you trying to get the value. `onChange`, `onSubmit`? `value` will always be an empty string if your script runs immediately.

Comment: #1 How do you expect to  extract the value without human event? #2 Do you want a kind of background process without the classic submit button? #3 Do you want to catch the submit event, perform some operation and then, send it to your backend /url ?

Comment: does the JS code appear after or before body? The HTML might not be rendered when the javascript is executed

Comment: the body is before the JS code. It should send it on Submit i guess, what i'm trying to do is just extracting the value of the textfield after pressing enter while the focus is on the textfield. Is there an elegant solution for this or would a submit button work better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't get any value because you need an event listener so JS knows to pull data once the field has been filled.

In the HTML form, add a button and then use an event listener to check when the button was clicked. Then, JS will know to grab the value of the input field.

**Without `preventDefault()`**

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('submitBtn');



btn.addEventListener('click', function() {

textervalue = document.getElementById("texter").value;

console.log(textervalue);

});
```

```html
<div class="splitscreen" >
    <div class="left">
        <video class="input_video"></video>
        <canvas class="output_canvas" width="960" height="540" id="rand"></canvas>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
        <canvas class="chat_canvas" width="250" height="500" id="rundrand" ></canvas>
        
        <form action="/url" method="GET" id="rand_text">
        <input type="text" id ='texter' value='Guess here' autocomplete ='off'>
        <button id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
        </form>
        
    </div>
</div>
```

**With `preventdefault()`**

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('submitBtn');



btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

e.preventDefault();

textervalue = document.getElementById("texter").value;

console.log(textervalue);

});
```

```html
<div class="splitscreen" >
    <div class="left">
        <video class="input_video"></video>
        <canvas class="output_canvas" width="960" height="540" id="rand"></canvas>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
        <canvas class="chat_canvas" width="250" height="500" id="rundrand" ></canvas>
        
        <form action="/url" method="GET" id="rand_text">
        <input type="text" id ='texter' value='Guess here' autocomplete ='off'>
        <button id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
        </form>
        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this seems to work but for some reason my console log clears after every submission and only every 1/5 times the submitted value/word is logged.

Comment: it seems as though the value isn't logged but still extracted, as i can output it otherwise and it still exists. Thank you very much!

Comment: @nohamagneng - The button submits by default. If you don't want it to submit, you use `preventDefault()` on the event. I updated the answer to show how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="/url" method="GET" id="rand_text">
        <input type="submit" onclick="fonctionHere(this)" id ='texter' value='Guess here' autocomplete ='off'>
        </form>




function fonctionHere(e) {
console.log(e.value);
}
```

submit is form action input directly.. and with an onclick, we have "this" it something like this same codes "getElementById" was send to the function directly

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).